# How to cache layer content and use it during resizing/animation?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, core-animation

I noticed that in macOS's Finder, when the sidebar is collapsing/expanding, the icon and texts are compressed or streched(see screenshot below). I guess this is an optimization that keep the layer from re-drawing during the animation.

I tried to write a custom `NSTableCellView` subclass that mimic that behaviour. But I don't know where to start, to be specific:

1. How to get notified when the animation starts so I can set the content of the layer.
2. How to re-draw the view or layer when the animation finishes so it doesn't use the cached content any more.

I started with the following scaffolding code. (The `draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect)` method will not be called when `wantsUpdateLayer` returns `true`. This may be an optimization according to [this doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/ImprovingAnimationPerformance/ImprovingAnimationPerformance.html))

```
     class TableCellView: NSTableCellView {

        override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
            print(#file, #line, "draw tcell view")
            super.draw(dirtyRect)

            // Drawing code here.
        }

        override var wantsUpdateLayer: Bool {
            print(#file, #line, "want")
            return true
        }

        override func updateLayer() {
            print(#file, #line, "update")
            super.updateLayer()
        }

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the view uses a layer as its backing store (`wantsLayer = true`), then you can set the view's [`layerContentsRedrawPolicy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483514-layercontentsredrawpolicy) to perform these same optimizations. By default (if AppKit created the layer), the content will be continually redrawn into the view’s backing layer during animated resizing:

> For a layer-backed view — that is, a view for which AppKit created the layer — AppKit sets the contents redraw policy to `duringViewResize` by default.

By for example setting the policy to `beforeViewResize` the view will redraw once at the beginning of the resize animation.

[`NSView.LayerContentsRedrawPolicy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview.layercontentsredrawpolicy) lists all the possible redraw policies.

Comment: Thanks. My views are layer-backed. I had noticed this `layerContentsRedrawPolicy` and tried setting it to `.beforeViewResize` and `crossfade`. It's not effective on Sierra. My other machine has been upgraded to High Sierra, I noticed **on that machine** it was effective on another view higher in the hierarchy, but I didn't try it with the `NSTableCellView `. On the Sierra it's not effective. I'm away from my High Sierra machine so I can only code on Sierra this week.